# RxJava reactive pull - moving buffer upstream

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a very fast producing source (and there is nothing I can do about that) and very slow consuming subscriber (in a rate that is dependent on User's actions).

I used RxJava's reactive pull model to handle this and no more events are delivered to the subscriber than I request so that is working fine. In the stream, between source and subscriber, I have one expensive network request.

```
fastProducingSource()
    .flatMapMaybe(event -> expensiveRequest(event))
    .subscribe(slowConsumingSubscriber)
```

I would like to delay this request until downstream requests more items and buffer items produced by the source before flatMapMaybe()

Comment: correct me if I wrong, but when the until the `slowConsumingSubscriber` will not request additional items, `fastProducingSource` will not emit, so the `flatMapMaybe` suppose to get notifications in the same rate as `slowConsumingSubscriber` gets

Comment: Well, for me the fast producing source is Geofire query wrapped in flowable: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java It will emit as many items as it it finds and I have no control over it. Therefore, I need a buffer somewhere in the stream to hold non consumed items and it would be ideal for the buffer to be placed before I am making another network call to fetch data based on geofire event.

Comment: I guess your `expensiveRequest(event)` `Maybe` is subscribed at some different Scheduler?